# Can I use the grounding rods of a main panel as the grounding rods for my sub panel

Tags: grounding

I ran 3 #6 B/R/W and 1 #8 Grn from my main panel through 1" sch 40 PVC to my garage and will be installing a 100A sub panel with separate ground and neutral blocks. I understand that since it is a separate building I need a grounding rod. I would like to know if I could run a # 8 bare copper wire to one of the two grounding rods of the main panel. The rod is about 7 feet from the wall I will be attaching my new sub panel to. This garage is 100 years old and solid brick only the roof is wood if that makes any difference. And should I install a 60amp GFCI breaker in the main panel for the main shutoff?

Comment: Can you explain more about how this building is "detached" and yet so close?  Is there any connecting structure of any kind?

Comment: This "garage" was originally a carriage house which are usually only a short distance away from the main house. ours is separated only by a 6 foot wide breezeway

Comment: What make and model is your main panel? Some 60A GFCI breakers can't feed split phase loads due to the fact they lack a load neutral lug...

Comment: When I google "breezeway" I see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=breezeway&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj50ez1vfniAhXx-yoKHWyLCxoQ_AUIECgB&biw=884&bih=1007). To confirm, you are saying there is a "roof-like structure" between the buildings?

Answer (score 3):

### It's not a separate building

Having a breezeway between the buildings means it is one building in the eyes of NEC.  You not only can use the same ground rods, you can simply use the ground wires you already ran.

Further, you do not require a shutoff switch (typically implemented as a main breaker) in the garage's panel. Although if you're committed to it, it does no harm.